# JavaScript: conditional formatting within document.createtextnode?

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of javascript that generates code like;

```
DOM_a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(t.headingText));
```

In this example **t.headingText** might (or might not) contain text that I want to display in a certain way, like bold. If the text ends up being "Holy Cow" I want it to display on my page as "**Holy** Cow"

How can I make this happen with this code? I know that I would need to append the child "b" calls but I dont know how to do that conditionally within a string.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just manipulate the text. Using your example

```
if( /holy/ig.test( t.headingText ) ) { // if word exists
    t.heading = t.headingText.replace( /(holy)/ig, "<span class="b">$1</span>" );
}
```

Then you can use normal css to style the `b` class.

Answer (score 0):

With `createTextNode` you're out of luck. You could use `innerHTML` somehow like this:

```
DOM_a.innerHTML = "<b>Holy</b> Cow";
```

and handle the condition with an if/else block in your code.